# Share.open return message as undefined on android device always once user share any content on other apps and return on actual app

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-share

Steps to reproduce

1. Install app in android device with react-native-share.
2. Share any image or message (Ex. Whatsapp).
3. Observe behavior that will stick it to Whatsapp not come back on your app again.
4. Press back 1/2 time now you again come on your app.
5. Store Share. open output and observe it.

Expected behavior

1. It should be returned likewise what return on ios device.
2. It should return automatically on the actual app once the share is done. (This might not be possible but very helpful if we can archive this looks like android default share behavior.)

Actual behaviour

1. ios output: {"message": "net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension", "success": true}
2. android output: {"message": undefined, "success": true}

Environment

React Native version: 0.63.4

React Native platform + platform version: Android

Typescript version (if using typescript): 3.8+ required, what version is in your environment?

react-native-share
Version: 7.1.1

Github issue: https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/1103